# Looking for a good book covering CURL library under c++

Tags: c++, curl, ftp, ftps

are there any good books/tutorials decscribing how to use CURL library under C++ to implement FTP / SFTP clients ? Thx for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the C++ bindings for CURL, see the docs at http://curlpp.org/ . There are extensive examples there; no need to get a book (in all likelihood).

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to find examples of how to: chdir,mkdir,mv,rm,ls. I can't find any of that on this page.  Maybe i should first read about libcurl and then jump to curlpp ?

Comment: You should learn how to use curl generally, either with regular libcurl or curlpp, before you learn specifics about the FTP protocol.

Answer (score 1):

I found the libcurl docs to be sufficient.  There are a couple examples of [FTP in C here](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/example.html).